# Is there a Clojure function for ordinal indicators?

Tags: clojure, ordinal, ordinals, ordinal-indicator

I want a function that will populate the contents of this map:

```
{:1 "first" :2 "second" :3 "third" :4 "fourth" ... :100 "one-hundredth" ...}
```

So I can do something similar to

```
(println "This is the " (:3 {... :3 "third" ...}) " item in the sequence")
> This is the third item in the sequence
```

Is there an existing Clojure library that does this?

My question is: **Is there a Clojure function for [ordinal](http://www.aaamath.com/nam23_x2.htm) [indicators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator)?**

(If there is a better way to describe this kind function - please let me know)

Comment: [clojure-humanize](https://github.com/trhura/clojure-humanize) offers conversion of numbers to human-readable strings, as well as ordinal indicators (albeit it only of the form `100th` instead of `one-hundredth`. But you can probably find some inspiration inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user=> (require '[clojure.pprint :as pprint])
nil
user=> (map #(pprint/cl-format nil "~:R" %) [1 2 3 4 100])
("first" "second" "third" "fourth" "one hundredth")
```

note that `:1` is not `1`, and `:` is not a syntax for map keys

```
user=> (pprint/pprint (into {} (map (fn [n] [n (pprint/cl-format nil "~:R" n)]) (range 20))))
{0 "zeroth",
 7 "seventh",
 1 "first",
 4 "fourth",
 15 "fifteenth",
 13 "thirteenth",
 6 "sixth",
 17 "seventeenth",
 3 "third",
 12 "twelfth",
 2 "second",
 19 "nineteenth",
 11 "eleventh",
 9 "ninth",
 5 "fifth",
 14 "fourteenth",
 16 "sixteenth",
 10 "tenth",
 18 "eighteenth",
 8 "eighth"}
nil
```